# Replace string :"{ using regex

Tags: .net, regex, replace

I have following string.

```
str= ""10":"{\"read\":\"1\",\"write\":\"0\"}"";
```

Now I want to replace string with `:"{` to `:{` and `}"` to `}` in above string using regex expression.

Can anyone guide me to replace the character using regex or can use only replace method.

Comment: It isn't clear what string exactly you have... Is `str=` *part* of the string or is it the variable name containing it?

Comment: You don't know Regexes so your solution is to ask someone to write a regex for you? use `string.Replace` and live happy.

Comment: What's wrong with string.Replace?

Comment: If you truly want to use string replacement in regex, try to find the regex using (a plethora of) services online, such as http://www.regexr.com/. Asking for "what is the regular expression for this exact string" is of little use to anybody else.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you don't need a regular expression for this. Just use

```
var str2 = str.Replace(":\"{", ":{").Replace("}\"", "}");
```

Comment: "I don't think"? You can be pretty sure of it